# A -Wshadow warning only for member variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, clang

I want to catch shadowing of member variables **only**, for example:

```
class MyClass {
    std::string _s;
    void foo() {
        std::string _s = "oops, shadows the member variable";
    }
};
```

The best I found was -Wshadow, but it's too broad and warns for local shadowing too. I was hoping to add such warning to Qt's CI with -Werror= as we've had some bugs with member shadowing. Adding -Werror=shadow simply won't fly as there's hundreds of warnings, all looking benign.

A MSVC-specific option would also work for me.

Comment: `-Wshadow` has various sub-modes (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) but none quite like what you want.